# С помощью LINQ развернуть таблицу значений вниз (VB.NET)

Tags: linq, vb.net

Прошу подсказать как развернуть вниз данные из строки вида:

```
1|25|желтый|синий|красный

2|29|синий|красный|желтый

3|32|зеленый|синий||
```

Эти данные считываю в массив `A`, затем из массива делаю `A.AsEnumerable` в `itemEnum`

`itemEnum` определена как `IEnumerable(Of String)`

дальше пишу

```
Devices = From line In itemEnum

          Let elements = line.Split("|"c)
          Let account = elements(1)
          Let devs = elements.Skip(2).Take(3)
          Select New With {.Accounts = account,
                           .devices = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(Function(i) devs.Skip(i * 3).Take(3))}'''
```

Но получаю ошибку

Как получить данные вида:

```
25

желтый

синий

красный

29

синий

красный

желтый
```

**Спасибо**

Сообщение об ошибке:
System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта "WhereSelectArrayIterator`2[System.String,VB$AnonymousType_3`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String]]]]" к типу "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Comment: В вопрос нужно добавить текст ошибки

Comment: `.devices = devs` внутри New. Непонятно, зачем там Enumerable.Range.